# Scala case matching with cons. Where does this variable h come from?

Tags: scala

I'm reading some Scala problems and I see this:

```
def last[A](l: List[A]): A = l match {
  case h :: Nil => h
  case _ :: tail => last(tail)
  case _ => throw new NoSuchElementException
}
```

I understand the basics of the cons operator. But where does the `h` come from?

In that top `case h`, I can see how we're saying in the event that there is `Nil` at the end of the list, return `h`, which would be the last element of the list. But where is `h` even defined?

Answer (score 3):

The `h` is defined right there in the `case` statement.

Scala's pattern matching has pretty concise syntax that can take a beat to get used to. It mixes some stuff that look very similar:

- If you include a literal value, the object you're matching on must be equal to that value. Example: `case 1 :: tail => ...` matches only lists that start with `1`.
- If you include an `_`, that matches anything. Example: `case _ :: tail => ...`
- If you include a new variable name, that matches anything, and assigns what it matched to that variable within the scope of the corresponding body. Example: `case h :: tail => ...` which matches the exact same inputs as the previous example but also assigns the first element to `h` within the "`...`" section.

Answer (score 1):

`h` is an identifier that represents a single element of type `A` and is defined in the `case` clause itself: the letter "h" is sensible in this context because it clearly means "head." However, you can use whatever legal Scala identifier you want:

```
def last[A](l: List[A]): A = l match {
  case baconWrappedShrimp :: Nil => baconWrappedShrimp
  case _ :: tail => last(tail)
  case _ => throw new NoSuchElementException
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scala pattern matching allows you to write temp variables in the cases.
The first case covers the case where l is a the following list {h, Nil}. Pay attention that the '::' operator is used to concatanate a single element with a list. Unlike the ':::' operator which concatanates two lists.